# How to exclude unwanted tags when using Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm practicing python scraping on indeed.com with Beautifulsoup.

While extracting 'job location' with [div class companyLocation],
what I want is to get the location string right after 'div class="companyLocation"'.
(in below html, "United States")

But for some cases, there are extra 'a aria-label' or 'span' clauses which contains unwanted strings such as "+1 location" or etc.

I couldn't figure out how to get rid of these.
So I ask for your advice.

```
<div class="companyLocation">United States
<span><a aria-label="Same Python Developer job in 1 other location" class="more_loc" href="/addlLoc/redirect?tk=1fgg7b6pa306m001&amp;jk=d724dab9a2d2af2c&amp;dest=%2Fjobs%3Fq%3Dpython%26limit%3D50%26grpKey%3DkAO5nvwVmAPOkxWgAwHyBwN0Y2w%253D" rel="nofollow">
+1 location</a></span>

<span class="remote-bullet">•</span><span>Remote</span></div>, United States+1 location•Remote
```

Here's my Python codes for your reference.
The problem arises 'if a.string is None:' case.

you could see above div + span html clauses with this code:
print(f"{a}, {a.text}")

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&limit=50"

extracts_url = requests.get(url)
extracts_soup = BeautifulSoup(extracts_url.text, 'html.parser')
soup_jobs = extracts_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "job_seen_beacon"})

for soup_job in soup_jobs:
    for a in soup_job.select("div.companyLocation"):
        if a.string is not None:
            pass

        #problem(below)
        if a.string is None:
            print(f"{a}, {a.text}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up the `if` statements, try the following instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&limit=50"

extracts_url = requests.get(url)
extracts_soup = BeautifulSoup(extracts_url.text, 'html.parser')
soup_jobs = extracts_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "job_seen_beacon"})

for soup_job in soup_jobs:
    for a in soup_job.select("div.companyLocation"):
        if a.string is not None:
            print(f"{a}, {a.text}")
```

Output:

```
<div class="companyLocation">United States</div>, United States
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation">Boulder, CO</div>, Boulder, CO
<div class="companyLocation">Houston, TX</div>, Houston, TX
<div class="companyLocation">Allen, TX</div>, Allen, TX
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation">New York, NY</div>, New York, NY
<div class="companyLocation">New York, NY</div>, New York, NY
<div class="companyLocation">New York State</div>, New York State
<div class="companyLocation">Austin, TX</div>, Austin, TX
<div class="companyLocation">Research Triangle Park, NC</div>, Research Triangle Park, NC
<div class="companyLocation">New York, NY</div>, New York, NY
<div class="companyLocation">Cary, NC</div>, Cary, NC
<div class="companyLocation">Raleigh, NC</div>, Raleigh, NC
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation"><span>Remote</span></div>, Remote
<div class="companyLocation">Houston, TX</div>, Houston, TX
<div class="companyLocation">Bellevue, WA</div>, Bellevue, WA
<div class="companyLocation">Houston, TX</div>, Houston, TX
```

Now it works just fine.

Comment: That was not my problem.  (a.string is not None case works fine as you said.)

The problem is that running the below case, you'd get "unwanted" extra strings other than the location.
  
if a.string is None:
            print(f"{a}, {a.text}")

Comment: the problem is that if a.string is None case you'd get unwanted extra strings other than th e locations as I mentioned above. thanks anyway.

Comment: @Zerwing What's the expected output?

Comment: should be as you posted (a.string is not None case)
In 'If a.string is None' case, you'll see : United States '+5 location' (+5 location not wanted; even for some cases it creates new lines as 'United States /n +5 location')

Answer (score 0):

is this working?

```
    #problem(below)
    if a.string is None:
        data=''
        for child in a.children:
            if not child.name and child != '':
                data+=child
        print(data)
```

Comment: not exactly as I wanted (I see blank lines), but many thanks for your help!